# Is a new Django migration necessary when adding a new member to an existing Enum class?

Tags: django, enums, django-migrations

Let's say I have a model `Pie`, and I add a field `flavor`, which is an `EnumTextField`.

```
class FlavorType(Enum):
    APPLE = 'apple'
    BANANA = 'banana'
```

Django auto-generates the migration:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='pie',
            name='flavor',
            field=django_apps.core.fields.EnumTextField(
                choices=[(django_apps.bakery.constants.FlavorType('apple'), 'apple'), 
                         (django_apps.bakery.constants.FlavorType('banana'), 'banana')],
                enum_cls=django_apps.bakery.constants.FlavorType
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

Let's say that later on, I add a new member, such as `FlavorType.CHERRY`:

```
class FlavorType(Enum):
    APPLE = 'apple'
    BANANA = 'banana'
    CHERRY = 'cherry'
```

**Question: Does a new `AlterField` migration need to be made to update `field.choices`?**

My guess is no, because we've already specified the `enum_cls`. I notice that `makemigrations` doesn't create a new migration file when this enum member is added. Additionally, I can save a new pie of flavor `cherry` to the database with no problem. If this is the case, then 1) I find it a little misleading that `choices` is even in the original migration and 2) I couldn't find any documentation about it. Any insight is appreciated!